# Stop coroutine from other script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I am making a game with a maze with audio hints on what way to go. I have the sounds playing on a coroutine and it work in terms of only starting once. However, what I need to do is be able to stop it from another script with a trigger on so that the audio does not keep playing when the player passes a certain point. This is my code so far.

```
public AudioSource direction;

private bool running = false;

IEnumerator AudioPlay()
{
    while (true)
    {
        direction.Play();

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    }

}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {

        if (running == false)
        {
            StartCoroutine(AudioPlay());

            Debug.Log("Started");

            running = true;
        }

        else if (running == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("Void");
        }

    }           

}
```

Comment: Tried `StopCoroutine(AudioPlay())?`

Comment: You could add a function to your main script to stop coroutine and then call it from your other script.

Answer (score 2):

#### Use `StopCoroutine(previouslyRunCoroutine)`

If you use the `IEnumerator` form (`StartCoroutine(AudioPlay());`) to start the coroutine, the Unity documentation [recommends](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html) that you save a reference to the `IEnumerator` and use that in future calls to `StopCoroutine`:

```
public AudioSource direction;

private bool running = false;
public IEnumerator audioPlayCoroutine;

IEnumerator AudioPlay()
{
    while (true)
    {
        direction.Play();

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    }

}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {

        if (running == false)
        {
            audioPlayCoroutine = AudioPlay();

            StartCoroutine(audioPlayCoroutine);

            Debug.Log("Started");

            running = true;
        }

        else if (running == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("Void");
        }

    }           

}
```

Then, in your other script you can use `StopCoroutine`:

```
OtherScript.StopCoroutine(OtherScript.audioPlayCoroutine);
```

If you were to use the method name form such as `StartCoroutine("AudioPlay");`, the documentation would recommend using the method name form to stop it:

```
OtherScript.StopCoroutine("AudioPlay");
```